# Is there a difference between "cilantro" and "culantro" in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, comida

I've seen the American English "cilantro" (British English "coriander") translated into Spanish as both *cilantro* and *culantro*. What is the difference? Are they synonyms used interchangeably, or is the difference regional? If it is a regional difference, where is each word used?

Comment: It's also called "coriander" in American English, but usually refers to the dried seeds, rather than the fresh leaves, and is usually ground and used as a spice.

Comment: @Flimzy: Ah, interesting. I'm not much of a cook.

Comment: But what, if any, are the differences in flavor in cooking? Are they interchangeable in cooking, as they are in usage of their names?

Comment: I love both but actually prefer the Culantro. A very dear friend gave me a Culantro plant.I am anxiously waiting for seeds to plant more of it.

Comment: Take into account that common names for plants or animals don't follow conventions like scientific names. The same common name may designate different species in different places, and the same species may receive different names in different places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia articles <sup>[1](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eryngium_foetidum), [2](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriandrum_sativum), [3](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroselinum_crispum)</sup>, there are three related species:

***Eryngium foetidum*** (**en:** culantro, Mexican coriander and long coriander; **es:** coriandro, cimarrón, culantro or recao), is originary from the tropical Americas (probably from Mexico), and has different common names including:
[image: Eryngium foetidum]
*«samat»* (Guatemala), *«cilantro de monte»* (Venezuela), *«culantro de pata»* (Honduras), *«culantro»* or *«chicoria»* (Nicaragua, Panamá, Cuba), *«cilantro ancho»* (República Dominicana), *«recao»* (Puerto Rico), *«culantro mexicano»*, *«culantro habanero»*, (México), *«culantro coyote»*, *«alcapate»* (El Salvador), *«sacha culantro»* (Perú), *«orégano de Cartagena»*, *«cilantro habanero»* (España), *«culantro cimarrón»* (Colombia), *«culantro coyote»* (Costa Rica).

I don't recognize the leave or the name, but that's probably because I am from Bogotá (relatively cold weather in the mountain) where the Old World coriander (see bellow) is more common.

***Coriandrum sativum*** (**en:** coriander, cilantro, Chinese parsley or dhania; **es:** cilantro) is probably originary from the Mediterranean.
[image]
While *«cilantro»* is the most common name in all the Spanish speaking world, the name *«culantro»* is also used in Perú and Honduras.

Note that the English name “coriander”, the Latin *coriandrum* and the Spanish *«culantro»* are cognates (word with a common etymology) (from Greek **κορίαννον** *koriannon*).  Also the word *«cilantro»* has the same etymology but has driven further away from the Latin word.

The third related herb is:

***Petroselinum crispum*** (**en:** parsley; **es:** perejil) - however there seems to be less ambiguity in the name.

While the three of them are from the same family *Apiaceae* (or *Umbelliferae*), this family also include carrots, celery, arracacha, anise, and dill among many other, and aparently the New World (*E. foetidum*) and the Old World (*C. sativum*) corianders are not to closely related taxonomically.

---

As for your question: while there is some synonymy, they are not the same species: *«cilantro»* is mostly used for Old World's *Coriandrum sativum*, while *«culantro»* is mostly used for New World's *Eryngium foedidum*.

And yes: there are regional differences and both words can refer to either of them in different countries.

Comment: Bravo for an extremely well-written answer. For those outside the Americas, particularly Europeans, I’d like to point out that the *Coriandrum sativum* plant produces both an herb from its fresh leaves and a spice from its dried seed, but **only the herb is ever referred to as *cilantro* speaking English in the United States;** the spice is always *coriander* even in America. Sin embargo, en el castellano de los EE.UU. vemos lo contrario, o sea que ambas formas se llaman *cilantro*,  no importa que sea hojas o que sea frutos. Sólo se distinguen en el inglés de estas partes, no en el español.

Answer (score 6):

Perejil is different.

Perejil = parsley (petroselinum crispum); looks the same as cilantro, but has a much milder, more neutral taste. (Parsley lacks the distinctive "soapiness" of cilantro that people seem to have such strong feelings about.

cilantro = (Amer. English) cilantro/coriander (Coriandrum sativum). Looks like parsley but with a stronger, slightly soapy flavor. Older generations often call it coriander, as it's known in Britain. Younger generations in the U.S. often know it as an ingredient in Thai, Mexican, Latin American, Indian, Vietnamese, etc., cuisine and usually call the leaves "cilantro," although the seeds and the ground spice derived from them are still usually called "coriander" in U.S. English.

culantro = (Eryngium foetidum), a different plant with different-shaped leaves. All three (parsley, cilantro/coriander, and culantro) are related to one another, and culantro's flavor is often described as a much stronger version of cilantro. In some dishes they can be interchangeable, but often they are not.

Their names, however, are somewhat idiosyncratic in Spanish, varying a lot from one region to another and sometimes going by different names entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I heard this plant being named cilantro or culantro in different countries across South America:

[image]

While the name of its seeds is "coriandro" (a very fragant spice):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cilantro is a different leaf than culantro. I'm in south America and we use culantro. Cilantro is harder to find here and culantro grows wild. Culantro has a stronger flavor but about the same taste as cilantro. They both look completely different. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely linguistic point of view **CI-lantro and CU-lantro are exactly the same thing = *Coriandrum sativum***, known in Spain since Roman times, way before the discovery of the Americas. That word variation comes from geographical and provincial dialectal differences in good old Spain.

That other totally unrelated tropical herb with a similar yet stronger fragrance, and which grows wild in many parts of the tropics and subtropics, ***Eryngium foetidum*, is neither cilantro nor culantro**. It has never existed in ***non tropical*** Spain, and today it still does not. But for lack of a proper international word, since it was not known before the discovery of the new world, and therefore had NO NAME in Spanish, people in different parts of the New World use different words to refer to it according to its smell, use and physical appearance. For *Coriandrum sativum* ***ONLY***, cilantro and culantro are ***BOTH CORRECT!!!***. For *Eryngium foetidum*, any local denomination goes (including your own personal one...). ***Eryngium foetidum*** is known as ***recao, Mexican cilantro***, etc.. in many places.

Comment: @Edgar Sosa-Mièles are you by chance the same person that wrote the answer? If so, you can check [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of that but I found [this](http://homecooking.about.com/od/cookingfaqs/f/faqculantro.htm). Hope it helps (emphasis mine):

> **Culantro** is a completely different plant from **cilantro**. Although the two are cousins, they look nothing alike and are quite easy to differentiate by appearance.
>
> **Culantro**, *Eryngium foetidum*, has long, serrated leaves and sports a blue flower when permitted to bolt. It is the leaves of culantro that are popular in Caribbean and Asian dishes.
>
> **Culantro** is also often called spiny cilantro and is not as widely available as cilantro. Check with your market's produce manager if you do not see any in with other fresh herbs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however just linking to an external site is not considered a valuable answer.  Can you summarize the article in your own words?

Comment: Hmm, but the [RAE](http://rae.es/culantro) says *culantro* is the same as *cilantro*.

Comment: As far as i know both are common names for Coriander sativum but that's exactly why scientific names are so important, the same common name can refer to different plants just going to the next town.

Comment: @Laura: Indeed; Wikipedia says about *Eryngium foetidum*: "In the United States, where it is not well known, the name culantro sometimes causes confusion with *Coriandrum sativum*".

Comment: That is called Perejil in some countries in South America

Comment: Is it just me, or doesn’t *culantro* sound like the punchline of some sort off-color pun/joke?

Comment: All I can say is that I do know 2 types of cilantro/culantro. Which one is called which is another story but one of them smells stronger than the other and has smaller leaves. The smell is about the same and taste is about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

http://bonnieplants.com/products/herbs/culantro

In Puerto Rico we use this and in other parts of various islands. It is a wonderful woodsy herb and can EASILY take Cilantro's part... For 3 leaves in one stew it can easily replace a whole bunch of cilantro.Literally a whole bunch. Save yourself the cash and use the Culantro for a better flavor and fragrant delicious stew.I wish you good cooking !

Answer (score 0):

They are definetly different, since one has long stems with short 3-4 pointed leafs at the end. Mostly used in Mexican and South American foods (Cilantro) and the other has also a long stem but the leaf is in it (Culantro or Reacao) and is mostly used in Caribbean foods. The latest has a stronger flavor and smell after cooked while the first has a stronger flavor and smell when uncooked. The images for each would be the ones provided by Carlos Esquenio Thompson. Americans are mostly used to Cilantro since it comes raw in Mexicans tacos and food cooked by them. While Culantro is most difficult to see in the States. I do used it in all my cooking and the strong smell was questioned by mexicans I used to rent from. The smell the same but again, one smells and tastes stronger when raw, the other when cooked. The Culantro taste, uncooked, is more like almost eating dirt while when cooked has a strong flavor. Meanwhile, cilantro can be eaten in both ways and taste delicious no matter if cooked or not.